# Clean way to run a cron after a certain time on Sunday and before a time on friday

Tags: linux, cron

I am looking for a way to run a script every two hours starting after a 1pm on Sunday and ending at 1pm on Friday.

Is there any special cron job syntax for this? 
The only way I can think of to do it this is something like:

```
00 */2 * * 0-5 [ [ `/bin/date +\%u` -eq 0 ] && [ `/bin/date +\%H` -gt 13 ] || \
                 [ `/bin/date +\%u` -eq 5 ] && [ `/bin/date +\%H` -lt 13 ] ] && /run_script.sh
```

Which feels kind of dirty...Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Adding tests for date/time can help, but you specify `0-5`, but then test only for `%u` = `0 or 5`. (using `&&`, which isn't right). What do you think will happen on days where `%u` = 1-4`? I would put that test inside of the `run_script`, or if you prohibited from modifying it, then make a wrapper script that calls `run_script`, after testing that current date/time is in-range and remove all the date/time testing from the crontab. You could make it real fancy and require an agrument for date/time checking to use that feature. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0 13-23/2 * * 7 /run_script.sh
0 1-23/2 * * 1-4 /run_script.sh
0 1-13/2 * * 5 /run_script.sh
```

3 entries seems easier for the eye?